# Standard way to check the hard drive temperature without installing additional packages

Tags: linux, configuration, hard-disk, monitoring, sensors

I want to check the temperature of my hard drive without installing `hddtemp` or `smartctl`. Is there a standard UNIX way to do this?

For example, to check the CPU temperature one doesn't need to install `lm-sensors`, one can just read `/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone*/temp` or `/sys/devices/platform/coretemp.0/hwmon/hwmon*/temp*_input`. `lm-sensors` just pretty-prints it. So there should be a file for the hdd temperature. I tried to look for the hdd temperature file in the `/sys/class/scsi_host` folder but couldn't find anything.

Comment: I don't think there's anything like that. Neither `smartctl -a /dev/sdX | grep -i tempe` nor `hdparm -H /dev/sdX` get their info by reading `/sys` files.

Comment: how do they get their info?

Answer (score 4):

ON linux 5.6+ Use drivetemp module to read disks sensors data using  HWMON infrastructure.

load module drivetemp:

```
sudo modprobe drivetemp
```

Then you can find the sensor data in /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon*/  together with the other sensors

https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/hwmon/drivetemp.html

Example to list all drives:

```
grep -l "drivetemp" /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon*/name | while read f;
    do printf "%s(%-.2s°C)\n" "`<${f%/*}/device/model`" "`<${f%/*}/temp1_input`";
done
```

Example to list drive by model:

```
grep -l "Lexar 256GB SSD" /sys/class/scsi_disk/*/device/model | while read f;
    do printf "%s(%-.2s°C)\n" "`<${f%}`" "`<${f%/*}/hwmon/hwmon*/temp1_input`";
done
```

Example to get only the temp by drive model:

```
cat "$(grep -l "Lexar 256GB SSD" /sys/class/scsi_disk/*/device/model | xargs dirname)"/hwmon/hwmon*/temp1_input
```

Example to list drive model:

```
cat /sys/class/scsi_disk/*/device/model
```

Comment: There seem to be a lot of stuff under `/sys/class/hwmon`. Can you please detail how we can read temperature from there ? Thanks

Comment: @ciprian-tomoiagă done

Comment: I've tried your method and it works fine for SATA drives. Do you know of anything similar for nvme drives ?

Comment: @pieroxy Try using sensors to read the temps

Comment: @mozlima the original question explicitly specify not using any program (sensors, smartctl or hddtemp)